# Can't play this video error in MacDonst videoplayer

Tags: android, cordova, video-player

I’m trying to play a simple .MP4 via the MACDONST plugin, but get an error reading “Can’t play this video” as soon as the video player is displayed. I can play the video file in the Android standalone video player, and I can call a Youtube video via the plugin. Many thanks for your help!  Here's my page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="video.js"></script>



       <script type="text/javascript">


        //app.initialize();

        function init()
         {
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", console.log('ready'), true);
        }

       function playVideo(vidUrl) {
        //alert("Starting Vid Script");
           window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(vidUrl);
      }
  </script>


   </head>
    <body onload="javascript:init()">
          <a href="#" onclick="playVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYOLV66XukY')">Play Stream</a><br>
          <a href="#" onclick="playVideo('file:///stigma.mp4')">Play File</a><br>
            <a href="#" onclick="playVideo('file:///sdcard/stigma.mp4')">Play File from SD</a><br>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same thing. Except I'm trying to play links to mp4s off my server. It works on a galaxy Tab 10 and Galaxy S3, but not a Galaxy 2 or Galaxy 4... But they'll play in the browser and natively in the video player, just not through the plugin...

Answer (score 0):

First you create directory in your www location directory I named videos.
then put your stigma.mp4 file into the videos directry then call your path like bellow mentioned

Play File

Note: your video file dose not contain any special character like (, & - &  _ etc..) only file file extention .mp4

Comment: This answer is not very clear, please consider editing for clarity.